# factorizing on a slice of a df

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to give numerical representations of strings, so I'm using Pandas'
`factorize`

For example Toyota = 1, Safeway = 2 , Starbucks =3

Currently it looks like (and this works):

```
#Create easy unique IDs for subscription names i.e. 1,2,3,4,5...etc..
df['SUBS_GROUP_ID'] = pd.factorize(df['SUBSCRIPTION_NAME'])[0] + 1
```

However, I only want to `factorize` subscription names where the SUB_GROUP_ID is null. So my thought was, grab all null rows, then run factorize function.

```
mask_to_grab_nulls = df['SUBS_GROUP_ID'].isnull()

df[mask_to_grab_nulls]['SUBS_GROUP_ID'] =  pd.factorize(df[mask_to_grab_nulls]['SUBSCRIPTION_NAME'])[0] + 1
```

This runs, but does not change any values... any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You should always share a subset of your data set so that others can use it to help you.

Comment: Just do `df.loc[mask_to_grab_nulls, 'SUBS_GROUP_ID'] = pd.factorize(...`.

Comment: @Timus this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Feel free to submit it as an answer and I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is called [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), which has two major downsides and should be avoided:

1. It can be slower than the alternative, because it involves more function calls.
2. The result is unpredictable: [Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing)

I'm a bit surprised you haven't seen a `SettingWithCopy` warning. The warning points you in the right direction:

> ... Try using `.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value` instead

So this should work:

```
mask_to_grab_nulls = df['SUBS_GROUP_ID'].isnull()
df.loc[mask_to_grab_nulls, 'SUBS_GROUP_ID'] = pd.factorize(
    df.loc[mask_to_grab_nulls, 'SUBSCRIPTION_NAME']
)[0] + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely related to chained assignments (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)). Try the solution below, which isn't optimal but should work fine in your case:

```
df2 = df[df['SUBS_GROUP_ID'].isnull()] # isolate the Null IDs
df2['SUBS_GROUP_ID'] = pd.factorize(df2['SUBSCRIPTION_NAME'])[0] + 1 # factorize
df = df.dropna() # drop Null rows from the original table
df_fin = pd.concat([df,df2]) # concat df and df2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
df=df.dropna(subset=['SUBS_GROUP_ID'])#drop null values
df_results =le.fit_transform(df.SUBS_GROUP_ID.values) #encode string to classes
df_results
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [**`numpy.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to factorize only the non nan values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'SUBS_GROUP_ID': ['ID-001', 'ID-002', np.nan, 'ID-004', 'ID-005'],
                   'SUBSCRIPTION_NAME': ['Toyota', 'Safeway', 'Starbucks', 'Safeway', 'Toyota']})
                   
df['SUBS_GROUP_ID'] = np.where(~df['SUBS_GROUP_ID'].isnull(), pd.factorize(df['SUBSCRIPTION_NAME'])[0] + 1, np.nan)
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]